# Determine if a path is legal

Tags: python, security

How can I check a user-supplied path is sanitised?

I want to ensure it has no wildcards nor any shenanigans.  Right now, I'm checking that it is not *escaping* the correct folder so:

```
if os.path.commonprefix([os.path.abspath(path),os.getcwd()]) != os.getcwd():
    # raise error etc..
```

But like all self-written security check code, I want it held up to better scrutiny!  And it doesn't address that the path is actually legal after all that.

I will then be using the path to *create* assets and such.

Comment: Are you just checking for a safe filename or are you including subdirectories as well? What will you be using this check for?

Comment: @Blender I am allowing the user to upload content to a remote "repository"; the file may not exist, and I don't want to be put artificial limitations on the naming and such, but I don't want ... shenanigans

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [Werkzeug's `secure_filename`](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/utils/#werkzeug.utils.secure_filename):

> #### `werkzeug.utils.secure_filename(filename)`
>
> Pass it a filename and it will return a secure version of it. This
>   filename can then safely be stored on a regular file system and passed
>   to `os.path.join()`. The filename returned is an ASCII only string for
>   maximum portability.
>
> On windows system the function also makes sure that the file is not
>   named after one of the special device files.
>
> ```
> >>> secure_filename("My cool movie.mov")
> 'My_cool_movie.mov'
> >>> secure_filename("../../../etc/passwd")
> 'etc_passwd'
> >>> secure_filename(u'i contain cool \xfcml\xe4uts.txt')
> 'i_contain_cool_umlauts.txt'
> ```